# Как преобразовать массив в строку python?

Tags: python

Вот парсер

```
import requests
import dateparser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mysql.connector

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    title=soup.find('h1').text
    date=soup.find('span',{'class':'news_date'}).text
    text=soup.find('p').text
    textp=soup.find_all('p')

    dateparser.parse('30 июля 2019, 13:48', date_formats=['%d %B %Y %H'])

    print(title)
    print(date)
    print(text)
    print(textp)



def main():
    url = 'https://www.zakon.kz/4979616-kazahstan-spustya-12-let-vyigral-zoloto.html'
    (get_data(get_html(url)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

И, когда идет вывод с парсера этих строк, эти данные являются массивом. Как мне их преобразовать в строку?

```
textp=soup.find_all('p')
print(textp)
```

Comment: попробуйте `print(str(textp))`

Comment: Спасибо но я нашел другой метод при принте я использовал метод join

Comment: отлично, а теперь удалите свой `join` и используйте вместо него `str`. На лицо лаконичность, понятность и отсутствие бесполезного цикла)

Comment: Viktorov  вы не правы,     print(str(['a', 'b'])) выведет строку:  ['a', 'b'].       А вот print(''.join(['a', 'b'])) выведет строку: ab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ:При print использовал метод join `print(str(textp))`

Answer (score 8):

```py
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
str_a = ''.join(a)  # 'abc'
```

Comment: я все никак не пойму. А чем `str` то не угодил?

Comment: @Viktorov посмотри как это будет выглядеть в результате и поймёшь)

Answer (score 0):

поставь "`*`" перед переменной:

```
(print(*textp))
```